# Ajax cross domain script blocking by IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cross-domain

I am accessing the data from jquery ajax method. It's working fine in Google Chrome and FireFox. But IE giving an error SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

```
$('#button').bind('change focusout', function () {
        $.ajax({
                    url: "http://zip.elevenbasetwo.com",
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: "zip="+$('#zip').val(),
                    success: function(result, success) {
                            $("#city").val(result.city);
                            $("#state").val(result.state);
                        },
                    error: function(result, success) {
                            $("#city").val("");
                            $("#state").val("");
                        }
        });
    });
```

What can i do to fix it ?

Comment: Q. Have you tried using JSONP instead of JSON for the data transfer? Q. is the website you are trying to access under your control? If not you can always wrap the service provided on your own website.

Comment: This is a property of modern browsers to prevent XSS. Try posting a proxy call to your server, which then makes a call to that server.

Comment: I changed dataType:"json" to dataType:"jsonp" it's again not working for me. Now i am getting error some callback issue. 

How can i make proxy call with jquery ?

Comment: w.open(h,b.url,b.async) i am getting an error in this line

Answer (score 2):

update the code like this

```
function callGetRequest() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://zip.elevenbasetwo.com",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        data: "zip="+$('#zip').val(),
        success: function(result, success) {
                $("#city").val(result.city);
                $("#state").val(result.state);
            },
        error: function(result, success) {
                $("#city").val("");
                $("#state").val("");
            }
    });
}
```

and call this method on button click like this

```
<button type="button" onclick="callGetRequest()">Button</button>
```

This code is working in all the browsers.